# Loader visible while upto ng-include completed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jsp

using angularjs to load a jsp page content in div tag. within the jsp page some text and button there. It was successful completed. But it take some time to load the jsp page content within the div. Here i'm using some class to load a loader `span`. I want to disable the loader after jsp content load in that div.

#### index.html

```
  <div ng-include="path"></div>
  <div>
       <span ng-show="loader" class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh-animate"></span>
  </div>
```

#### angular.js

```
  $scope.path='https:/..../url.jsp?orderNo='+$scope.orderNo+'&amount='+$scope.amount;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer and forgot to post them

```
$rootScope.$on('$includeContentLoaded', function(event) {
    $scope.loader = false;
});
```